# I completed the week 5 speller cs50x today. The code was not giving the correct output when I used recursion, but normally, it worked

Tags: c, recursion, cs50

Here is the link to the question (problem set)[speller](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/5/speller/)
I find the recursion conditions correct. the problem is in the check function, according to the outputs. So when I changed it, the code worked.
Here are the codes from dictionary.c (first one with recursion and the second one without it)

#### with recursion

- here I defined two functions of my own in order to recursively go through the lists...

```c
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

bool search(node *s, const char *wod);
void frr(node *ptr);

int sije = 0;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
// ans - i would choose a 2d array which is [26][LENGTH + 1]
const unsigned int N = 26;

// 2d Hash table
node *table[N][LENGTH];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // finding the hash for the word
    int h = hash(word);
    // finding the length for the word
    int len = strlen(word) - 1;
    // creating another pointer for the sake of iterating
    node *tmp = table[h][len];
    return search(tmp, word);
}

bool search(node *s, const char *wod)
{
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!strcasecmp(s -> word, wod))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        s = s -> next;
        bool c = search(s, wod);
    }
    return false;
}





// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    return toupper(word[0]) - 'A';
}







// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // make the hash table free of garbage values
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            table[i][j] = NULL;
        }
    }



    // TODO
    // open the dictionary file
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // read the word inside a char array
    char n[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", n) != EOF)
    {
        // call the hash function and get the hach code
        int h = hash(n);
        // this will return something from 0 till 25
        int len = strlen(n) - 1;
        // this will have the length of the word

        // let's load it to the hach table
        // create a new node
        node *no = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (no == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // copy the word from n to no
        strcpy(no -> word, n);
        // declare the pointer inside the node to null
        no -> next = NULL;
        // insert the node inside the hach table
        if (table[h][len] == NULL)
        {
            table[h][len] = no;
        }
        // else if the spot is populated
        else
        {
            no -> next = table[h][len];
            table[h][len] = no;
        }
        sije += 1;

    }
    return true;

}





// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return sije;
}





// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
        {
            // if table at that inces in not null,
            // that means that there is a linked list at that index of the table
            if (table[i][j] != NULL)
            {
                frr(table[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}



void frr(node *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    frr(ptr -> next);
    free(ptr);
}
```

#### without recursion (the one which worked)

```c
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

void frr(node *ptr);

int sije = 0;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
// ans - i would choose a 2d array which is [26][LENGTH]
const unsigned int N = 26;

// 2d Hash table
node *table[N][LENGTH];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // finding the hash of the code
    int h = hash(word);
    // finding the length of the code
    int len = strlen(word) - 1;
    // creating another pointer for the sake of iterating
    node *tmp = table[h][len];
    while (true)
    {
        if (tmp == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!strcasecmp(tmp -> word, word))
        {
            return true;
        }
        tmp = tmp -> next;
    }

}






// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    return toupper(word[0]) - 'A';
}







// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // make the hash table free of garbage values
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            table[i][j] = NULL;
        }
    }



    // TODO
    // open the dictionary file
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // read the word inside a char array
    char n[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", n) != EOF)
    {
        // call the hash function and get the hach code
        int h = hash(n);
        // this will return something from 0 till 25
        int len = strlen(n) - 1;
        // this will have the length of the word
        // let's load it to the hach table
        // create a new node
        node *no = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (no == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // copy the word from n to no
        strcpy(no -> word, n);
        // declare the pointer inside the node to null
        no -> next = NULL;
        // insert the node inside the hach table
        if (table[h][len] == NULL)
        {
            table[h][len] = no;
        }
        // else if the spot is populated
        else
        {
            no -> next = table[h][len];
            table[h][len] = no;
        }
        sije += 1;

    }
    fclose(dict);
    return true;

}





// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return sije;
}





// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
        {
            // if table at that inces in not null,
            // that means that there is a linked list at that index of the table
            if (table[i][j] != NULL)
            {
                frr(table[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}



void frr(node *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    frr(ptr -> next);
    free(ptr);
}
```

What could be the reason. All others are correct, only the checking part ...

Comment: Hello.  In your search function, if s == NULL, the function returns a Boolean value of "false", if the "strcasecmp" function is successful, the function returns a Boolean value of "true"; however, in the recursive call section (the "else" section) the function makes a recursive call but does not then return anything.  That is probably your issue.  You probably need to add a line of code such as "return c;".

Comment: FYI, as a quick test, I built a prototype program that included your search function.  When this program was compiled, there were two compiler warnings relating to my previous comment about not returning the Boolean value in the function.  They were "warning: unused variable ‘c’ [-Wunused-variable]|" and "warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|".  I would guess that you received similar warnings in your compilation for the recursive function.

Comment: HELLO, I tried returning the recursive call but it still shows the same error as it does in the code above. It counts all the words as mispelled.

Comment: @NoDakker sorry for the incorrect code. edited the search . now it does not show error, but still buggy.

Comment: That seems odd.  I can only offer up one other suggestion in your recursive function.  If instead of having the statement "bool c = search(s, wod);" you could replace that statement with "return search(s, wod);" and see if that makes a difference.  It's the only other thing I can suggest short of using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would investigate this issue further as it seemed to me that adding in a return within the "else" block should address the issue.  Possibly, I was not making the answer clear enough via the comments so I went ahead and acquired the lesson code, implemented your code solution with the non-recursive check function performing some test over a select set of text files, and then trying out the code with the recursive search function along with the code tweak I had noted.

Executing the non-recursive solution over the "aca.txt" file, the following was the terminal output to be used as the baseline.

```
WORDS MISSPELLED:     17062
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        376904
TIME IN load:         0.08
TIME IN check:        3.61
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.01
TIME IN TOTAL:        3.70
```

I then revised the program, dictionary.c, to include the check/search function calls with the code in its original state.

```
// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // finding the hash for the word
    int h = hash(word);
    // finding the length for the word
    int len = strlen(word) - 1;
    // creating another pointer for the sake of iterating
    node *tmp = table[h][len];
    return search(tmp, word);
}

bool search(node *s, const char *wod)
{
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!strcasecmp(s -> word, wod))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        s = s -> next;
        bool c = search(s, wod);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Executing this version of the code did give some superfluous misspelling values when run over the same file.

```
WORDS MISSPELLED:     359710
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        376904
TIME IN load:         0.07
TIME IN check:        4.85
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.01
TIME IN TOTAL:        4.93
```

My guess is that this is the type of behavior you were experiencing.

I then revised the search function to provide a return statement within the "else" block as I had noted in the comments.  Following is the refactored code.

```
// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // finding the hash for the word
    int h = hash(word);
    // finding the length for the word
    int len = strlen(word) - 1;
    // creating another pointer for the sake of iterating
    node *tmp = table[h][len];
    return search(tmp, word);
}

bool search(node *s, const char *wod)
{
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!strcasecmp(s -> word, wod))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        s = s -> next;
        return search(s, wod);      /* Added this line of code */
        //bool c = search(s, wod);  /* Deactivated this line of code */
    }
    return false;
}
```

When the program was recompiled and executed over the same text file, the following statistical output was acquired.

```
WORDS MISSPELLED:     17062
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        376904
TIME IN load:         0.08
TIME IN check:        4.14
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.01
TIME IN TOTAL:        4.23
```

This agrees with the values listed with the non-recursive version of the program.

I checked this refactored version against the other selected text files and all agreed with the values run using the non-recursive version of the program.

FYI, I utilized the gcc compiler.  That is the compiler that I have on my system in lieu of Clang.  And I will point out one other thing I needed to do to make successfully build this program.  When compiling, the compiler complained about having a variable size definition for the "table" array.

```
const unsigned int N = 26;
```

To get around this issue with my compiler, I had to move the assignment/definition of "N" to the same spot as the "LENGTH" definition in the header file.

```
// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45
#define N 26
```

I don't think these additional tweaks had any bearing on the functionality of using a recursive function, but I wanted to be fully transparent.

Anyway, hopefully with this expanded explanation, you might try out the code tweaks to see if the recursive function would now work.